# how to minify javascript by omitting repeating function

Tags: javascript

```
function ban(id, S) {S.match(/[a-z]/i)  && id !==
MPP.client.getOwnParticipant()._id  &&
MPP.client.sendArray([{m: "kickban", _id: id, ms: 3e4}])}

var R = pp => {ban(pp._id, pp.name)};

MPP.client.on("participant added", R);
MPP.client.on("participant update", R);
MPP.client.on('a', A => ban(A.p._id, A.a));
```

It detects alphabet from chat and nickname and bans when it does.

MPP.client.on("", R) repeats twice, and i wonder if there's any way I can code this using one of it.

Comment: Are you trying to find a minifier that does this/otherwise affect minified code (i.e. saving bytes over the network), or do you actually mean you want to not repeat yourself to simplify/make things more readable (i.e. refactoring)?

Comment: Also, what’s `MPP.client`?

Comment: I guess you could `var on = (...args) => MPP.client.on(...args);`. If you want fewer characters you can also omit semicolons. But I'd prefer to write readable code, and leave the minification for automatic tools

Answer (score 1):

Your code is very nice as is. By creating the function and assigning it to `R`, you guarantee that the function object is only created once even though it appears twice as an argument:

```
MPP.client.on("participant added", R);
MPP.client.on("participant update", R);
```

If the two look-alike calls bother you a little, you *can* write:

```
["added", "update"].forEach((action) => {
    MPP.client.on(`participant ${action}`, R);
});
```

and this will minimize the words you have to type twice.

However, consider the cost in degrading readability a little bit. If, however, you had maybe five or more such calls, then yes, a loop like this *would*, I think, be an improvement. :)